# Closing menu from code via datepicker selectionchanged event freeze the application

Tags: wpf, datepicker, menuitem

Solved : i used the Calendaer_Closed Eevent insted
but why the application got stuck i don't know 
maybe becuse it was in the middle of some action at the changed event

When I select a date from the `DatePicker` I try to close the menu and my application freezes.
This is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication9"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="500">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
     <Menu Height="40" >
        <MenuItem Header="First" x:Name="_menuItem">
            <MenuItem Header="Date" StaysOpenOnClick="False">
                <MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="False" >
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged"/>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Content="click" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _menuItem.IsSubmenuOpen = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception thrown when debugging?

Comment: *changed the xaml i was testing while copy-paste here,NO excpetions

Comment: Why do you want it to close when picking a date? I found it confusing as I got no feedback that I had selected a date. The look and feel was like an error.

Comment: there is another feedback on the window , big change in view. how can i close the question ?